# Convex Optimization: can differentiability of a function be defined with respect to a closed set?

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis, definition, convex-optimization

In Boyd and Vandenberghe, there is the following definition:

[image]

So the the authors first define differentiation at points in the interior of the domain, next, if the domain happens to be open also (interior domain == domain), then $f$ is said to be  differentiable.

My question is, what if the domain is closed? Then is $f$  by definition "not differentiable"?

My only concern is that this definition seem to be overly restrictive. Imagine a function that is differentiable everywhere in the interior of the domain, i.e., $f(x) = x^2$ over $[1,2]$ or $([1,2), (1,2])$, then just because the domain is closed (or not open), therefore the function is not differentiable. But the same function  $f(x) = x^2$ over $(1,2)$ is differentiable.

Please let me know if my interpretation of the author's definition is correct and whether my concerns are justified.

Comment: The notation is strange. If the function is written as $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, then the domain ought to be $\mathbb{R}^n$ (at least, that's how function notation usually works). Hence referring to "$\text{dom} \ f$" is needless--- $\text{dom} \ f$ is precisely $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You could simply say that the function is differentiable on the interior of the domain.  It's not differentiable at boundary points in the domain, and you should want that to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that a function is differentiable without specifying where is just a shorthand for saying that the function is differentiable at all points in its domain, which does require that the domain be open. This is because to fully discuss diffentiability at a point, you need to examine the behavior of the function in every direction from the point.

If a function does not have an open domain, then it cannot be differentiable at the non-interior points, so when discussing differentiability, you have to specify a set of points instead of just making a blanket assumption of differentiability everywhere.

Saying that $f : [0,1] \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto x^2$ is "not differentiable" simply means that it is not differentiable at *every* point in $[0,1]$. Which it isn't. It is not differentiable at $x = 0$ or $x = 1$, since it isn't defined on one side of each of those points. But that does not in any way deny its differentiability at every point of $(0,1)$. It just means that when examining the behavior of $f$ at some point $x$ in its domain, you cannot simply assume that $f$ will be differentiable there.